# How to use MySQL DECIMAL?

Tags: mysql

I can't quite get a grasp of MySQL's DECIMAL. I need the row to be able to contain a number anywhere from 00.0001 to 99.9999. How would I structure it to work like so?

Comment: Ended up here and read the answer claiming that DECIMAL UNSIGNED not being possible. See the fresh answer below for the correct spec for this.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-decimal/

Answer (score 508):

DOUBLE columns are **not** the same as DECIMAL columns, and you **will get in trouble** if you use DOUBLE columns for financial data.

DOUBLE is actually just a double precision (64 bit instead of 32 bit) version of [FLOAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). Floating point numbers are approximate representations of [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) and they are not exact. In fact, simple numbers like 0.01 do not have an exact representation in FLOAT or DOUBLE types.

DECIMAL columns are exact representations, but they take up a lot more space for a much smaller range of possible numbers. To create a column capable of holding values from 0.0001 to 99.9999 like you asked you would need the following statement

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
(
    your_column DECIMAL(6,4) NOT NULL
);
```

The column definition follows the format DECIMAL(M, D) where *M* is the maximum number of digits (the *precision*) and *D* is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the *scale*).

This means that the previous command creates a column that accepts values from -99.9999 to 99.9999. You may also create an UNSIGNED DECIMAL column, ranging from 0.0000 to 99.9999.

As an example, if you want a column that accepts values from -9999.99 to 9999.99 the command would be `DECIMAL(6,2)`. As you can see, you still use a *precision* of 6, but only allow a *scale* of 2.

For more information on MySQL DECIMAL the [official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) are always a great resource.

Bear in mind that all of this information is true for versions of MySQL 5.0.3 and greater. If you are using previous versions, you really should upgrade.

Update on MySQL 8.0.17+

[Unsigned is deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) for FLOAT, DOUBLE, and DECIMAL columns.

Comment: Voted up your answer. Your answer is correct, the other answer is not (since it claims that "double = decimal"). DECIMAL is a fixed-point type with an exact value and its synonyms are NUMERIC, DEC and FIXED. Not DOUBLE, because DOUBLE is a floating-point type that represents approximate numeric data values. When using DECIMAL(<1-65>, <0-30>), the first parameter is the number of digits, the second the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Take note that is work for MySQL 5.0.3 onwards, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-examples.html

Comment: @ajreal - could you amend your answer accordingly?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't DECIMAL(6,4) capable of holding values from -99 to 99.9999 not 0.0001 to 99.9999?

Comment: The poster asked for a decimal field that held values between 0.0001 and 99.9999. I added some extra information to clarify that the field created actually supports values from -99.9999 to 99.9999. Thanks for the feedback! Also added MySQL version disclaimer.

Comment: You said "There is no way to create an "unsigned" DECIMAL column", yet your code example indicates "DECIMAL(6,4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL". Why is this?

Comment: Thats embarrassing, that UNSIGNED slipped into the code when I answered the original question and I never noticed that my explanation refutes it! MySQL will actually return a syntax error with the original CREATE TABLE :(  Edited for correctness.

Comment: @AlexRecarey I seem to be able to create a DECIMAL UNSIGNED just fine; and the manual for MySQL 5.x agrees: `DECIMAL[(M[,D])] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]`. It will return an out-of-range error for negative values. You can likewise create unsigned FLOAT and DOUBLE. Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: We had to move from double to double when we had saved the currency and sometimes credit-debit reports had a minor variation in the application

Comment: @MarkusAO yep, you're right, UNSIGNED is valid since 5.0.3. Thanks!

Comment: DOUBLE TROUBLE!

Comment: To be a little more precise, DECIMAL is able to represent non-repeating base 10 numbers exactly.  DOUBLE is perfectly capable of representing certain numbers exactly (such as any integer) they just have be non-repeating in base 2.  Neither datatype is capable of representing the vast majority of "real numbers" exactly, but then neither can humans in general so nobody cares.

Answer (score 99):

Although the answers above seems correct, just a simple explanation to give you an idea of how it works.

Suppose that your column is set to be `DECIMAL(13,4)`. This means that the column will have a total size of 13 digits where 4 of these will be used for precision representation.

So, in summary, for that column you would have a max value of: `999999999.9999`

Answer (score 22):

There are correct solutions in the comments, but to summarize them into a single answer:

You have to use DECIMAL(6,4).

Then you can have 6 total number of digits, 2 before and 4 after the decimal point (the scale). At least according to [this](https://www.mysqldatatypes.com/#numeric).

Answer (score 11):

MySQL 5.x [specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) for decimal datatype is: `DECIMAL[(M[,D])] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]`. The answer above is wrong (now corrected) in saying that unsigned decimals are not possible.

To define a field allowing only unsigned decimals, with a total length of 6 digits, 4 of which are decimals, you would use: `DECIMAL (6,4) UNSIGNED`.

You can likewise create unsigned (ie. not negative) FLOAT and DOUBLE datatypes.

---

**Update on MySQL 8.0.17+**, as in [MySQL 8 Manual: 11.1.1 Numeric Data Type Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html):

> "Numeric data types that permit the UNSIGNED attribute also permit SIGNED. However, these data types are signed by default, so the SIGNED attribute has no effect.*
>
> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the UNSIGNED attribute is deprecated for columns of type FLOAT, DOUBLE, and DECIMAL (and any synonyms); you should expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL. Consider using a simple CHECK constraint instead for such columns.

Comment: Why is "unsigned" deprecated for the decimal data type in MySQL 8? MySQL doesn't use support domains, so all this means that we must now use a check constraint if we want to prevent negative values. It's no big deal but I don't see what is gained from this change.