# MySQL DECIMAL data type

Tags: mysql

I have a column in MySQL with the type DECIMAL(2,1). When I insert the number 10 into the database it reads 9.9. I want it to read 10.0. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use MySQL DECIMAL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834390/how-to-use-mysql-decimal)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`DECIMAL(2,1)` means (as the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) suggests) a decimal of 2 characters wide (in total!) and 1 decimal. If you want `10.0`, you need `DECIMAL(3,1)` (three wide, one decimal).