# What is the Best MySQL Database Formatting Type for GPS Coordinates?

Tags: php, mysql, database, decimal, rounding

I have a script which is inserting latitude and longitude into the MySQL database.  I have assigned these rows as:

```
`gpslat` DECIMAL(11,4)  NOT NULL ,
`gpslong` DECIMAL(11,4)  NOT NULL ,
```

For some reason, when I pass the string `gpslat=45.7834` and `gpslong=78.7834` I am getting a value in the database without the full string as `gpslat=45.0000` and `gpslong=78.0000`

Any ideas why this is not just sending the complete values?

---

PHP Addition:

```
function upload($lat, $long) {

if (gpsData['error']==0) {
    $result = query("INSERT INTO gpsTable(gpslat,gpslong) VALUES('%d','%d')",$lat,$long);
}
```

I have the `$lat` and `$long` values being passed in this case as `$lat=45.7834` and `$long=78.7834`

Query Function:

```
function query() {
global $link;
$debug = false;

//get the sql query
$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);

//secure the input
for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}

//build the final query
$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;

//execute and fetch the results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

    $rows = array();

    if ($result!==true)
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($rows,$d);
    }

    //return json
    return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
    return array('error'=>'Database error');
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP code is not the problem? If you are using parameterized queries (as you should), are the parameters the correct types? Showing us the code you used might help.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664735/mysql-decimal-data-type

Comment: @TheClouds I don't this any relation with the current post, his column type is correct. Presto, please add the php code you use to feed your table, and the one to retrieve the data too.

Comment: If you are doing extensive location-based work, you may be interested in using the [MySQL Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) instead of "raw" decimal fields.

Comment: @OlivierH I have added the PHP that has the insert query.

Comment: @MosheKatz  thanks for the suggestion on Spatial Extensions.  I am reviewing this now as well, looks like a great resource.

Comment: What is the `query(...)` function code ?? Try first to remove quotes between your values : `VALUES('%d','%d')` to `VALUES(%d,%d)`

Comment: @OlivierH I have just added the `query` function code.  Also I attempted removing the single quotes but the values are still rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `%d` in your query, and there is no MySQL call on PHP that uses that format (MySQLi uses `?` and PDO uses real names), I assume that your `query` function is using the `sprintf` function to build the SQL query. (**UPDATE:** I see from your update that I was right.)

According to the [documentation for `sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), a `%d` means (emphasis mine):

> the argument is treated as an **integer**, and presented as a (signed) decimal number.

The correct format string for you to use would be `%f`:

> the argument is treated as a **float**, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).

(or, if you do not want the input to be locale-aware, use `%F` instead.)

---

(In any case, if you are accepting this data from a user (or from a user-controlled device), you really should be using parameterized queries (docs for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)), instead of rolling your own SQL query builder.)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  Yes I agree that I need to use parameterized queries.  I will be cleaning it up in the long run, just trying to build the basic structure right now.  I uploaded the `query` function if you have any quick suggestions on parameterizing the query I would greatly appreciate it.  Otherwise I will review your references and clean it up in the long run.  Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look at [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for prepared (ie parameterized) `mysqli_` queries. The thing is to use `prepare` and `bind_param` methods.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out and get it all cleaned up.

Comment: Another suggestion: Unless you're doing math on the coordinates (and maybe even then), you might consider storing them as strings rather than floats. It uses a bit more storage space, but avoids any precision issues you might run into with values that can't be exactly represented in floating point format.

Comment: @GeminiDomino As long as you set the proper precision on the column definitions (which, in this question, is specified as 4 places after the decimal point), precision isn't an issue.

Comment: @MosheKatz You're right, of course. DECIMAL(M,D) isn't stored as floating point, but the OP could still have trouble converting to float in sprintf, no? Or has that been addressed too? As you might imagine, I've spent the last *mumble* years avoiding messing with floats as much as possible. :)