# Decimal data type cuts off numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a decimal data type in mysql. I set it to 6,2 but it won't allow 12105. It defaults to 10000 any time a number is inputted higher than 10000. How can I allow numbers like 12105 up to 5000000 and more.

Comment: A MySQL decimal type of `6,2` is six digits wide, of which two are decimals, i.e. 9999.99. If you want to allow larger numbers make the column bigger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL DECIMAL data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664735/mysql-decimal-data-type)

Comment: Thank you. I looked through several posts and none of them answered them, but that one does! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This is a dup but I can't find it.  DECIMAL(x,y) means the total number of digits (left OR right of the point) is `x`.

So, if you want to store between 0 and 999999.99, you need to define it as `DECIMAL(8,2)`

Comment: ah! so 101010.00 is really 8 places not 6? So if the x encompasses the numbers after the decimal point. What does the y stand for?