# MySQL Decimal Type Out Of Range Error

Tags: mysql

This code:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `my_db`;
CREATE DATABASE `my_db`; 
CREATE TABLE `my_db`.`my_table` (
    `id` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `multiplier` decimal(18, 10) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) Engine=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table` (`multiplier`) VALUES (100000000.0);
```

Returns an error:

```
Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'multiplier' at row 1
```

Why? There are only 9 digits before comma whereas the column should work until 18 digits - or am I missing something here? Thank you.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834390/how-to-use-mysql-decimal

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`decimal(18, 10)` means 10 digits after decimal and 8 before decimal, not  until 18 digits

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

> For example, a DECIMAL(18,9) column has nine digits on either side of
>   the decimal point, so the integer part and the fractional part each
>   require 4 bytes. A DECIMAL(20,6) column has fourteen integer digits
>   and six fractional digits. The integer digits require four bytes for
>   nine of the digits and 3 bytes for the remaining five digits. The six
>   fractional digits require 3 bytes.