# SQL SUM Returning Incorrect Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the SUM from the columns returned by a subquery but the value I'm getting back is not what I'm expecting.

When I run this query:

```sql
SELECT
    totals.repair_order_amount_total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            auto_repair_order.id,
            auto_repair_order.repair_order_amount_total
        FROM
            auto_dealer
            INNER JOIN auto_custom_auto_dealer_c ON auto_custom_auto_dealer_c.auto_custo60bd_dealer_ida = auto_dealer.id
            AND auto_custom_auto_dealer_c.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_customer ON auto_custom_auto_dealer_c.auto_custo0932ustomer_idb = auto_customer.id
            AND auto_customer.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_vehicluto_customer_c ON auto_vehicluto_customer_c.auto_vehic9275ustomer_ida = auto_customer.id
            AND auto_vehicluto_customer_c.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_vehicle ON auto_vehicluto_customer_c.auto_vehic831dvehicle_idb = auto_vehicle.id
            AND auto_vehicle.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_repairauto_vehicle_c ON auto_repairauto_vehicle_c.auto_repai4169vehicle_ida = auto_vehicle.id
            AND auto_repairauto_vehicle_c.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_repair_order ON auto_repairauto_vehicle_c.auto_repai527cr_order_idb = auto_repair_order.id
            AND auto_repair_order.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_ro_labrepair_order_c AS aro_lab_pivot ON aro_lab_pivot.auto_ro_laada9r_order_ida = auto_repair_order.id
            INNER JOIN auto_ro_labor AS labor ON aro_lab_pivot.auto_ro_la1301o_labor_idb = labor.id
        WHERE
            1 = 1
            AND COALESCE(auto_repair_order.technician_id, '') != ''
            AND auto_repair_order.service_open_date >= '2021-06-25'
            AND auto_repair_order.service_open_date <= '2021-06-25'
            AND auto_dealer.id = '4e7ef95a-050a-b123-3c3a-4f74ae60fc96'
        GROUP BY
            auto_repair_order.id
    ) as totals
```

I get the following:

[image: Query Result]

When I try to SUM the repair_order_amount_totals though, the number I'm getting is *2373.36* when it should be *3,675.26*

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(totals.repair_order_amount_total)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            auto_repair_order.id,
            auto_repair_order.repair_order_amount_total
        FROM
            auto_dealer
            INNER JOIN auto_custom_auto_dealer_c ON auto_custom_auto_dealer_c.auto_custo60bd_dealer_ida = auto_dealer.id
            AND auto_custom_auto_dealer_c.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_customer ON auto_custom_auto_dealer_c.auto_custo0932ustomer_idb = auto_customer.id
            AND auto_customer.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_vehicluto_customer_c ON auto_vehicluto_customer_c.auto_vehic9275ustomer_ida = auto_customer.id
            AND auto_vehicluto_customer_c.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_vehicle ON auto_vehicluto_customer_c.auto_vehic831dvehicle_idb = auto_vehicle.id
            AND auto_vehicle.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_repairauto_vehicle_c ON auto_repairauto_vehicle_c.auto_repai4169vehicle_ida = auto_vehicle.id
            AND auto_repairauto_vehicle_c.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_repair_order ON auto_repairauto_vehicle_c.auto_repai527cr_order_idb = auto_repair_order.id
            AND auto_repair_order.deleted = 0
            INNER JOIN auto_ro_labrepair_order_c AS aro_lab_pivot ON aro_lab_pivot.auto_ro_laada9r_order_ida = auto_repair_order.id
            INNER JOIN auto_ro_labor AS labor ON aro_lab_pivot.auto_ro_la1301o_labor_idb = labor.id
        WHERE
            1 = 1
            AND COALESCE(auto_repair_order.technician_id, '') != ''
            AND auto_repair_order.service_open_date >= '2021-06-25'
            AND auto_repair_order.service_open_date <= '2021-06-25'
            AND auto_dealer.id = '4e7ef95a-050a-b123-3c3a-4f74ae60fc96'
        GROUP BY
            auto_repair_order.id
    ) as totals
```

Any idea why I might be getting a different value than I'm expecting when attempting to get the SUM?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the amount you're getting is not 2372.36? If so, that would mean that the "1,302.90" was not being included, which would suggest it is a string with a comma in it and so it isn't being regarded/automatically cast as a number. At a guess.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Actually, `1,302.90` will be treated as `1`, so the result he's getting is to be expected.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Turn that into an answer, using `REPLACE(totals.repair_order_amount_total, ',', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find where the problem is, you should look for suspicious coincidences between what you're expecting, what you get, and the data.

In this case, 3675.26 - 2373.36 = 1301.90, which is really close the value "1,302.90" in the data. Thanks to [user Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68168188/sql-sum-returning-incorrect-result#comment120479720_68168188), we see that MySQL is parsing the string into a number - but only up to the comma.

The bodge method to fix it would be to remove the comma:

```
SUM(REPLACE(totals.repair_order_amount_total, ',', ''))
```

The correct method would be to [use the DECIMAL type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834390/how-to-use-mysql-decimal) for all money amounts in the database, and use the UI to format the numbers with commas for display.